# load a large text file to a list in R

Tags: r, list, text, large-files

So I have textfile that contains data in the right format that it should be to be inside a list in R but it is 14 Mb and apparently a 2Mb is a limitation? I need to load this text file into R as a list.

There is another post here but that command (see below) just errors out

```
inlist <- strsplit(readLines("myList.txt"), "[[:space:]]+")
```

thanks
What I mean by what it looks like since it is huge here how it starts

```
structure(list(inputsTrain = structure(c(-73, -69, -48, 13, -86, -147, -65, -71, -32, 100, -73, -196, -102, 37, 14, 55, ........
```

Comment: What do mean "in the right format that it should be a list inside R?" Please make a reproducible example of your problem. (and what does *just errors out* mean? Where are you getting this `2mb` limitation?

Comment: I have a 871,061,080 byte file in memory at the moment and it's only filling up a small fraction of total space. I have in the past had files with 7 MB rows and 100 columns, so whatever limitation you are imagining it's not as small as you have heard.

Comment: It is way to huge to paste it here. Basically there is an old package that does a certain manipulation to a dataset and creates a list in a certain way. I used the output of this function to use with my data so I can use this list downsteam.

Comment: Ok @DWin how do you u make a text file to a list that works? thx I just know that cause it tells me, 2mb limits I did not pull it out of thin air; and my computer is top of the line mac with 32 gig ram

Comment: I would bring it in with `readLines()` then parse it as needed. If it had a specific structure there might be a function to do it. Details, we need details.

Comment: If you actually made a reproducible example (obviously not cutting and pasting your 14 mb file, but an small example file perhaps), but AT LEAST showing the code you used that is giving you an error, AND the error message it is returning, then perhaps we could help.

Comment: readLines() is from my own example and does not work sir thx

Comment: Use `dget(file)`? If the file is result of `dput` (which it appears to be). In future, don't save as  text file, use `saveRDS` instead to serialize it.

Comment: What does the most recent edit have to do with the question?

Comment: Others where complaining to see what was in my data but I am going to remove it because you are right it does not. They just complained and gave -1 :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that your data is the result of `dput(mylist, file = 'mylist.txt')`

I would suggest using the inverse of `dput`, which is `dget`

```
inlist <-dget('mylist.txt')
```

which simply is a wrapper for

```
eval(parse(file = 'mylist.txt'))
```

I've tested this on a 9mb file, without error or warning.

For example

```
dput(as.list(seq_len(1e6)), 'foo')
# foo is a 9.3 megabyte file
x <- dget('foo')
# works nicely
```

In future, don't save R objects as ascii representations, instead use `saveRDS` to save a serialized version, which can be read by `readRDS`